# Unsupported gpu architecture compute_30 on a CUDA 5 capable gpu

Tags: cuda, nvidia, yolo, nvcc, darknet

I'm currently trying to compile Darknet on the latest CUDA toolkit which is version 11.1. I have a GPU capable of running CUDA version 5 which is a GeForce 940M. However, while rebuilding darknet using the latest CUDA toolkit, it said

> nvcc fatal   : Unsupported GPU architecture 'compute_30'

compute_30 is for version 3, how can it fail while my GPU can run version 5
Is it possible that my code detected my intel graphics card instead of my Nvidia GPU? if that's the case, is it possible to change its detection?

Comment: Your darknet build harness will need to be changed to remove the reference to `compute_30` in order for it to be usable with CUDA 11.x.  CUDA 11.x no longer supports compute capability 3.0.  This particular error has nothing to do with the GPU you have (this is a compile-time issue, and the compile process does not depend on a particular GPU).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Support for `compute_30` has been removed for [versions after CUDA 10.2](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.2/pdf/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes.pdf). So if you are using nvcc make sure to use this flag to target the correct architecture in the build system for darknet

```
-gencode=arch=compute_50,code=sm_50
```

You may also need to use this one to avoid a warning of **architectures are deprecated**.

```
-Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets
```

Comment: While a correct observation, how does this answer the question? What should be done to solve the problem?

Comment: For anyone else reading this question and to answer @talonmies' comment, somewhere in your Makefile you should find a reference to `compute_30`. You can replace it with `compute_50`. 
In the case of darknet, as an example, `compute_20` is already commented out: `#      -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] \ This one is deprecated?`. You can do the same with `compute_30` to comment it out as there are other `compute_##` flags specified that will take its place (`compute_35`, `compute_50`, `compute_52`).

Answer (score 1):

I added the following:

```
makefiletemp = open('Makefile','r+') 
list_of_lines = makefiletemp.readlines()
list_of_lines[15] = list_of_lines[14]
list_of_lines[16] = "ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \\\n"

makefiletemp = open('Makefile','w')
makefiletemp.writelines(list_of_lines)
makefiletemp.close()
```

right before the
#Compile Darknet

```
!make
```

command. That seemed to work!

Comment: That's one way to edit a file!